# Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum User unauthenticated after login OR Error: "Route [login] not defined"

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I am using Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum.

While hosting on `localhost` for both api and client, login attempt is success and user response is getting back.

But, after uploading to server (api: [api.repairtofix.com](https://api.repairtofix.com) & client: [admin-control.repairtofix.com](https://admin-control.repairtofix.com)) login seems to be success while user details is not getting back. I get error with 401 `{message: "Unauthenticated."}`

ie. It works on `npm run dev`, but after `npm run generate` it doesn't work

**nuxt.config.js**

```
axios: {
    credentials: true
},
auth: {
strategies: {
    'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'https://api.repairtofix.com',
        endpoints: {
            login: {
                url: '/api/login',
            },
        },
    }
}
```

},

**LoginController.php**

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if(!auth()->attempt($credentials)){
        throw AuthenticationException();
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/login', LoginController::class);
```

**cors.php**

```
"Accept"=>"application/json",

'paths' => ['api/*', '/user', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**.env**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.repairtofix.com
SANTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=admin-control.repairtofix.com
```

**Login.vue**

```
data() {
    return {
        login: {
            email: 'nmg.gta@gmail.com',
            password: 'password'
        }
    }
},
 
methods: {
    
    async userLogin() {
        try {
            let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', { data: this.login })
            console.log(response)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error message got on Network tab]

[image]

Comment: When/where do you have this error?

Comment: I am facing this error from 6 day ago, and testing on right now, The error occurs while login button is pressed. error can be seen on https://admin-control.repairtofix.com/login

Comment: Where does it appear in the code?

Comment: Sorry I  don't know how to debug where it occurs

Comment: Try some `console.log`/`print` and find which one is next to the error call.

Comment: In development build it is working, error occurs after generating production build

Comment: Hm, not sure that this is somehow related. What is your `nuxt.config.js` and how do you generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

In **sanctum.php** file I forgot to add my domains. After adding I got the resopnse from /user